# Preencher campo com "00-00-0000" quando for vazio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou fazendo uma gravação no banco (PostgreSQL) com Python, uso uma base em `.txt`.

Problema: Na base tem alguns registros estão em branco, e está dando erro na hora de gravar, ocorre nos campo de Data. gostaria de saber como faço pra colocar um `if` ou uma `Exception` pra preencher com por Ex: `00-00-0000` nesses casos. 
 
Eu posso até colocar a tabela inteira em Var Char, mas 
 `data_ingresso = valores[12]` eu preciso gravar como Data mesmo, pq vou fazer conta com ela no banco.

Caso a estrutura da pergunta esteja ruim posso tentar melhorar.

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect( database='cap',host='localhost', user='postgres', password='**********')
cur = con.cursor()
ref_arquivo = open("C:/Users/br0151338587/Desktop/!Alertas/ampla_Novo_Tempo_Ordens_GA.txt",'r')

input("Conexão OK - Enter para continuar")
sql = 'truncate "tb_ordens_ga"'
cur.execute(sql)


for linha in ref_arquivo:
    linha = linha.replace("'","")
    linha = linha.replace('"','')
    valores = linha.split("|")


    numero_ordem = valores[0]
    data_exec_visita = valores[1]
    data_estado_format = valores[2]
    numero_cliente = valores[3]
    cliente = valores[4]
    endereco = endereco = valores[5]
    telefone = valores[6]
    bairro = valores[7]
    municipio = valores[8]
    des_servico = valores[9]
    descricao_etapa = valores[10]
    descricao_estado = valores[11]
    data_ingresso = valores[12]
    observacao_executante = valores[13]
    observacao_atendente = valores[14]

    sql = 'insert into "public"."tb_ordens_ga"("numero_ordem","data_exec_visita","data_estado_format","numero_cliente","cliente","endereco","telefone","bairro",' \
      '"municipio","des_servico","descricao_etapa","descricao_estado","data_ingresso","observacao_executante","observacao_atendente"'') \
       values('+"'"+numero_ordem+"'"+', '+"'"+data_exec_visita+"'"+', '+"'"+data_estado_format+"'"+', '+\
      "'"+numero_cliente+"'"+', '+"'"+cliente+"'"+', '+"'"+endereco+"'"+', '+"'"+telefone+"'"+', '+"'"+bairro+"'"+', '+"'"+municipio+"'"\
      ', '+"'"+des_servico+"'"+', '+"'"+descricao_etapa+"'"+', '+"'"+descricao_estado+"'"+', '+"'"+data_ingresso+"'"+\
      ', '+"'"+observacao_executante+"'"+', '+"'"+observacao_atendente+"'"+')'
    cur.execute(sql)
    con.commit()

ref_arquivo.close()

con.close()
```

<sup>[Imagem - Código](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4nRi.png)</sup>

Comment: Você não pode querer gravar uma data de "0000-00-00" no banco: esse dia _não existe_ no calendário gregoriano. Marquei a questão como duplicata de uma onde trato a questão detalhadamente, mesmo a pergunta não sendo idêntica.

Answer (score -1):

Trate antes de construir a query:

```
data_exec_visita = '00-00-0000' if valores[1]=='' else valores[1]
data_estado_format = '00-00-0000' if valores[2]=='' else valores[2]
```

faça um teste antes para ver se o retorno de `valores[1]` e `valores[2]` é realmente `''` quando voce diz que esta "vazio".

Comment: Lembrando que `00-00-0000` não é uma data válida, e o postgresql não vai aceitar essa data

Comment: Sim, @nosklo, me limitei mostrar minha solução para a pergunta dele, mas ele pode trocar por um valor válido.

Comment: Sim, bem lembrado, mas usei um valor valido aqui.

Comment: Se a resposta serviu, considere dar o aceite (Tick verde abaixo dos votos).

Comment: Eu não acho que uma resposta que considere usar essa data, sem esclarecer que não é uma data válida seja construtiva. (É inválida no sistema de datas usado por nós, humanos, fora do computador - não é só inválida "no postgres" ou "no Python")

Comment: @jsbueno A resposta utilizou o dado que ele trouxe na pergunta. Vc notou isso?